# Program received signal EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm stuck with a problem in emulator. The emulator occasionally stops with

Program received signal:  "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" .

as console output. No further info provided. Is there a chance to come closer to the problem?

Comment: Did you try running it in the debugger?

Answer (score 3):

I see that NSZombie already has been proposed, but the link doesn't seem to work anymore, so here's instructions on how to use it.

To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received the release message.

Answer (score 0):

This often is caused by sending a message to an object that is no longer in memory. There is no error message because there is nothing on the stack when the error occurs. You can set breakpoints and step through your application until you find where the crash occurs, or you can use nszombie.

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/02/nszombie-and-xcode-oh-my/

Comment: It's not caused just by sending a message to an object no longer in memory, it is caused by trying to access memory that you do not have access to. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will give you the same error.

Comment: maybe it should say "often caused by"